# Default import cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store with TypeScript. I have also installed `@types/redux-mock-store` which has `export default createStore`.

I have tried importing using:

```
import createStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import * as createStore from 'redux-mock-store';
```

TypeScript does not show any errors for the first import, but when I actually run the code it doesn't work since I get `redux_mock_store1.default` is not a function.

The second attempt works properly when I actually run my tests, but TypeScript complains "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature" saying that the default export of `@types/redux-mock-store` has no compatible index signatures.

How can I properly import or use module so that TypeScript doesn't report any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the latest version of `redux-mock-store` introduced a breaking change that breaks both the library and the associated typings. See the issue on [Github](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store/issues/135). You can just revert to the last working version:

```
yarn add --dev redux-mock-store@1.4.0
```